# Issue with multibyte character in Unix

Tags: unix, utf-8, multibyte

We are facing issue for multibyte character when we are trying to run the below command:

awk 'length<30'

The File content is :

ASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIOPZXJM0000023  حكمت مزبان إبراهيم العزاوي
ASDFGHJKLQWERTYUIOPZXJM000

So it should give only one record.

Answer (score 0):

```
length<30
```

Will always return true - you want the length() function, length is a simple variable which is initialized as zero.

```
awk  'length($0)<30'
```